# Sum of N numbers whose sum is M

Tags: combinatorics

In how many ways can we sum N nonnegative numbers (that is, taking values 1, 2, 3...) such that their sum is M? I found this problem doing convolution of series and combinatorics has never been my strong point.

Thank you!

Precision: The precise question is, I have a sum:
$$
\sum_{i_1,...,i_N=0}^\infty f\left(\sum_k i_k\right) = \sum_M C^N_M f(M)
$$
and I want to know what the coefficient is.

Comment: What do you mean by "in how many ways can we sum ..."?  You already know the sum, it's $M$.  Do you mean how many $N$-tuples have sum $M$?

Comment: Yes, that is the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you distinguis by order of the summands, this is simply $M-1\choose N-1 $ by a classicla stars-and-bars argument.

Comment: This is not exactly what I search for, I did the necessary modifications.

Comment: @JuanSimões : I think that this is exactly what you want.

Comment: @Juan: See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28probability%29). If you mean a sum of $N$ positive numbers (‘taking values 1,2,3, ...’), that’s exactly what you want. If you mean a sum of $N$ non-negative numbers, you want $\binom{M+N-1}{N-1}=\binom{M+N-1}M$.

Comment: Ok, I just saw I did not write well the question. Brian's answer is exactly what I wanted. Thank you all!

Comment: @Hagen Could you please explain how this result is derived?